# Unix command to rename multiple files

Tags: rename

I have some dirs with different `plugin-cfg.xml` files that I want to take a backup of and keep in the same dir.

E.g.

```
Plug6_a1/plugin-cfg.xml
Plug6_a2/plugin-cfg.xml
Plug6_a3/plugin-cfg.xml
```

How can I make a copy of `plugin-cfg.xml` rename to `plugin-cfgbk.xml` for each directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
find Plu*_a* -type f -name plugin-cfg.xml -exec \
  sh -c 'cp "$1" "$(dirname "$1")"/plugin-cfgbk2.xml ' sh {} \;
```

For every file named `plugin-cfg.xml` located under a directory which name starts with `Plu` and contains `_a`, make a copy of `plugin-cfg.xml` to `plugin-cfgbk2.xml` in the same directory.

Comment: Sorry there's a couple of mistakes on my part there.

Plug6_a1/plugin-cfg.xml
Plug6_b2/plugin-cfg.xml
Plug6_c3/plugin-cfg.xml

Make a copy of plugin-cfg.xml rename to plugin-cfgbk.xml for all dir

Comment: and please better explain "Make a copy of plugin-cfg.xml". Where should this copy go ? Are all the xml files named plugin-cfg.xml ?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to copy it into the same dir so the orignal and backup are there. all plugin-cfg.xml are named the same but have different configurations in them. Thanks for advise and will amend the question.

Comment: Can the down-voter explain what he thinks is wrong in my reply ?

Answer (score 1):

```
dest=/path/to/backup/destination;
find plu6_a1 plu61_a2 -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    cp -- "$f" "${dest%/}/${f%.xml}-bk.xml"
done
```

Find every XML file in plu6_a1 plu61_a2, make a copy, add the suffix -bk.xml to the copy and move it to "$dest".

EDIT: This code is written in Bash and it also requires GNU or BSD find(1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that requires only `/bin/sh` (this only works for a single directory, however):

```
for f in ./*.xml; do cp "$f" "${f%cfg.xml}cfgbk.xml"; done
```

Assuming you have bash 4+ (if you don't know, you probably do; check with `bash --version`), you can use globstar for recursiveness:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.xml; do cp "$f" "${f%cfg.xml}cfgbk.xml"; done
```

You might want to consider a clearer naming scheme for your backups, however -- I would prefer something like appending '.backup' to the filenames.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.xml; do cp "$f" "$f".backup; done
```